# array is not running in the right way in my pycharm

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pycharm

```
from numpy import *
from array import *

Vals = array('i', [1,3,5,6])

print(Vals)
```

And in the out put I get

```
array('i', [1,3,5,6])
```

How I can fix it and when I installed numpy I installed it in terminal because it needed visual studio something

Comment: What is wrong with the output? What do you expect?

Comment: numpy defines a function called `array`, so when you `import *` from it you overwrite the `array` name, so it's no longer the name of the standard module

Comment: never use `import *`, always controll what you import and only what you need

Comment: I expected to get only [1,3,5,6]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using numpy there's little need for the `array` module.  A typical way to express this initialization might look like:

```
import numpy as np    # np alias for the lazy typist

vals = np.array([1,3,5,6], dtype=int16)   # or dtype=int32 if you want 4-byte integers
```

which when printed

```
print(vals)
```

prints

```
[1 3 5 6]
```